# How do I see the release notes for an npm package before I upgrade?

Tags: node.js, npm, package, semantic-versioning

Does the npm registry expose release notes in a standardized way? I've seen release notes in:

- The README.md
- On GitHub as a tagged release with no description
- On GitHub as a tagged release with a description

While SemVer at least lets me know if there's a breaking change, it would be really nice to review what features or bug fixes a package author may have added.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is no such standardization as it's completely up to the project developer(s) to define how such information is conveyed. Some might have a `NEWS` file, others might have a `Changelog.md`, or yet others may have it in the places that you mentioned. The locations and file formats can vary widely.

It is possible that npm could adopt some optional thing that can automatically display some plaintext file using some kind of fixed naming scheme (and possibly falling back to a git diff if a git repo is defined in `package.json`), but as of this writing there is no such feature.

Comment: is it still the same?

Comment: @NasifImtiazOhi Yes

Comment: is it still the same?