# Is there a recent changelog somewhere for amazon-cognito-identity-js?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

The library is here - https://www.npmjs.com/package/amazon-cognito-identity-js

I know that Amazon has Amplify and that it's all a bit of a mess, but I can see that they're pushing new version of that library and yet I have no idea what changed between versions. Surely the changelog or some release history is there somewhere? Anyone knows?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I see the release notes for an npm package before I upgrade?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34971504/how-do-i-see-the-release-notes-for-an-npm-package-before-i-upgrade)

Comment: No, of course not. I'm looking for information that Amazon provides, in whatever form. There's no such thing as meaningful "automated changelog", unless you want to consider a diff output be it.